# Unable to locate persister Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

Estoy creando una aplicación en spring boot en la cual ocupo una dependencia que usa hibernate.

Al momento de correr la aplicación me sale el error `org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: mx.exm.comun.modelo.entidad.persona.Persona`.

Estoy tratando de usar oracle pero las aplicaciones no se inician cada vez.
Aquí está el seguimiento de la pila:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-09-27 14:46:54 ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:765)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204)
    at com.ejemplo.imagenesCeph.ImagenesCephApplication.main(ImagenesCephApplication.java:53)
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: Unable to locate persister: mx.exm.comun.modelo.entidad.persona.Persona; nested exception is org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: mx.exm.comun.modelo.entidad.persona.Persona
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at mx.exm.siirfe.comun.dao.hibernate.ciudadano.CiudadanoDAOImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5185d100.get(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.ejemplo.imagenesCeph.ImagenesCephApplication.run(ImagenesCephApplication.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:781)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: mx.exm.comun.modelo.entidad.persona.Persona
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.locateEntityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:687)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:3056)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1900(SessionImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2807)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2793)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1241)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1097)
    at mx.exm.siirfe.comun.dao.hibernate.GenericHibernateDAOImpl.get(GenericHibernateDAOImpl.java:73)
    at mx.exm.siirfe.comun.dao.hibernate.GenericHibernateDAOImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a9e7862e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Clase.java

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource(value = { "classpath:repositorioImagenes.xml" })
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "mx.org.ife.rfe.siirfe.comun.ceph.simple", "mx.ine.rfe.siirfe.servicios.imagenes.api" })
public class ImagenesCephApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private CiudadanoService ciudadanoService;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static Logger loger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImagenesCephApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ImagenesCephApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        loger.info("En ejecución");
        ciudadanoService.recuperaFotografiaPersona(19999991);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.19.1.51:1521:BD");
        dataSource.setUsername("usuario");
        dataSource.setPassword("contraseña");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com");
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ejemplo</groupId>
    <artifactId>imagenesCeph</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>imagenesCeph</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mx.exm.servicios.imagenes.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>imagenes-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar Saludos.

Comment: Tu error parece ser porque tienes especificado el paquete `sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com");` y tus entidades están en `mx.exm.comun.modelo.entidad.persona.Persona;` por eso no encuentra la entidad Persona, cambia el paquete de `com -> mx.exm.comun.modelo`.